# Italics used for the plural treatment of words?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, apostrophe, italics

Do these look right to you? I'm pluralizing the following words. In doing so, I'm italicizing the word to be pluralized but not the 's':

*and*s (instead of and's)
*wherefore*s (instead of wherefore's)
*his*s (instead of his's)

Answer (score 0):

The first two look fine, but his-s still reads as hiss because the reader won't notice the non-italicised 's'. In what context is it being used?

Perhaps try 'his's instead. It's obvious then what you mean.

> The professor said "He used too many 'his's in his sentence."

Comment: The professor said, "He used too many his's in his sentence."

Comment: Perhaps bold is better or both

Comment: "He used too much hissing in his sentence."

Comment: He used the word 'his' too often.